# How to automatically add browser prefix to CSS3 properties?

Tags: css, prefix

As you may be know, because CSS3 is not compatible with all of browsers when we use CSS3 we should add a prefix to CSS3 properties (like -moz, -webkit, -o and ...)

It is difficult to write these prefixes manually. So, is there any plugin, program or another thing to detect CSS3 properties in my CSS file and append necessary vendor prefixes to those properties ?

Comment: Compass + SASS will be your friend. http://compass-style.org/

Comment: sublime text combined with zen coding will automatically add the prefixes

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017560/css-framework-that-automatically-handles-vendor-prefixes

Comment: My personal favorite is web essentials 2012, and R#.

Comment: @RobertMcKee What is Web Essentials 2012 and R# ?

Comment: They are visual studio plug-ins http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6 and http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ea4ac039-1b5c-4d11-804e-9bede2e63ecf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options that come to mind, depending on your use-case:

- SASS with [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/)
- SASS with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/)
- Less with [LESS elements](http://lesselements.com/)
- [Emmet
  CSS3 Abbreviations](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/) (In your text editor)
- [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) (client side js)

My personal preference is to use Compass, but the Emmet abbreviations work well if you do not want the overhead of using a CSS pre-processor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more

Sublimetext plugin https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer?source=c

Comment: Autoprefixer has a [lot of tools](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer). Text editor plugins is a worse of them and I (as author of autoprefixer) don’t recommend it, because CSS with prefixes difficult to read and edit.

Answer (score 0):

A nice vendor prefix mixin for doing that in SASS [here](http://www.stefanwienert.net/blog/2012/05/18/easy-css-vendor-prefix-mixin-for-sass/) for those that are using SASS