# Is there a css prefixer for C#?

Tags: c#, css, razor

When writing CSS there are some style values that require a prefix (-webkit-, -moz-...). Is there any C# parser out there that can add this vendor specific prefixes? (Free, open source>).

I would like to add a HttpHandler that would return the browser specific CSS, while writing without adding prefixes.

I should note [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935761/add-automatically-browser-prefix-to-css3-properties) - it dose not provide a suitable c# answer.

(Similar to http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/).

I am working in VS.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I will add that to the question (remember that I want a parser that I can control).

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f may help.

Comment: Doesn't work (at least my version) with vendor specific internal names, for example: backgound:linear-gradient(...)