# How to add missing browser-specific css declaration properties and prefixes to epub

Tags: css, epub, emmet, epub3

Publishers sometimes release Epub titles without including all of the required browser-specific css declaration properties and prefixes.  For example, a title might include a `-webkit-transform` declaration but omit `transform` or vice versa.

There are a number of tools available to assist developer workflow in the creation of new content [Stackoverflow: How to automatically add browser prefix to CSS3 properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935761/how-to-automatically-add-browser-prefix-to-css3-properties); however, I am looking for a way to parse an entire Epub and add any missing properties.

Comment: Trying to get my head around the down vote.  Does not show any research or effort: The question clearly shows that I researched existing tools.  How is it unclear?  To whom is it not useful?

Comment: Drive-by downvote, don't worry about it. Perhaps the downvoter was worried about the fact that you initially seemed to be asking for a tool, which is off-topic at SO. However, in such cases the preferred response is to vote to close (which he probably also did), not downvote. Whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that all the relevant CSS is in `.css` files. You can open the epub by unzipping it, and this will expose the CSS files, wherever they might be. You can then simply run these through your favorite prefixing tool, then zip the book back up.

The problem is that AFAIK prefixing tools typically expect the `transform` property and add the `-webkit-transform` counterpart. I am not sure these tools will work if only `-webkit-transform` is there and you want `transform` to be added. You'll have to check each tool to see if it provides this behavior. In the worst case, you could write your own plugin for a CSS transformation framework like rework to do what you need.

Comment: Looks like reworkcss should do the trick.  Will try to find a way to share my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving the problem using postcss with plugins postcss-unprefix and autoprefixer.  postcss-unprefix removes existing prefixes and autoprefixer then adds any needed ones.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var postcss = require('postcss');

var input = process.argv[2]; // the source of the css
var output = process.argv[3]; // where to write the output

fs.readFile(input, 'utf8', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    processCss(result, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        } else {
            fs.writeFileSync(output, result, "utf8");
            process.exit(0);
        }
    })
});


function processCss(cssString, callback) {
    postcss([require('postcss-unprefix'), require('autoprefixer')])
    .process(cssString, { from: 'in.css', to: 'out.css' })
    .then(function ( error, result ) {
        if (result) {
            callback(String.trim(result.css));
        } else {
            callback(null, error);
        }
    });
}
```